# control desktop maximize area in C#

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, maximize

Is there a way to control what space of the screen windows can be maximized to, in C#

Comment: You mean, you want to control what happens when somebody clicks on the "maximize" button in a WinForms app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the size of your application's window, use the [Form.MaximizedBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizedbounds%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) property. You can use the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class to get the bounds of your current (or some other) screen.

For example, this will maximize your form to left half of the primary screen:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set width to 1/2 of screen
        Rectangle screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        screenBounds.Width = screenBounds.Width / 2;            
        this.MaximizedBounds = screenBounds;

        // maximize
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

**[Edit]**

If you want to dock your window to one side of the screen and limit the remaining desktop area for other applications, 
you might be interested in registering a custom APPBAR through Windows API.

Check the following links:

- Microsoft: [Creating an Application Desktop Toolbar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134206)
- CodeProject: [AppBar using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx)
- CodeProject: [C# does Shell, Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx)

Comment: No I'm looking at controlling the remaining windows. 
Like, I want to say this control docks like a toolbar to the edge of the screen, and now when windows maximize, they don't intersect my window.